# Setting up a simple A/B testing with PHP

Tags: php, testing

I have a webpage on my site - or really it's a web application and this page is sort of the dashboard (have to be logged in).

I'd like to try two designs for a panel that appears on the right of the page.

I have the 2 panel designs and I can easily track when each is clicked but how do I deliver these alternative verisons?

- should i just somehow load them alternatively when the page is loaded (that would mean one person sees them both)
- should I flag the users as being either a or b and they only ever see that version?

and how do I evenly deliver it so that visitor 1 gets A, visitor 2 gets B etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a hash of a user's IP address and then mod 2 to get a 0 or 1 value.

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$hash=md5($ip);
$number = hexdec( substr($hash, 0, 4));
$version = $number % 2;

if( $version == 0) {
  // show A
} else {
  // show B
}
```

This is good because a single user will always see the same version, and it will spread user's evenly across both versions.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends how heavyweight a solution you want.  Jon's solution will work provided users aren't NAT'd, but you could add a session if you wanted to prevent that issue.  If you want a more involved and flexible option there are a myriad of tools out there including [phpab](http://phpabtest.com/)