# How to randomly assign a variant to the visiting user?

Tags: php, lamp

As part of my project, I have four variants (webpages) that I want to randomly (and evenly) assign to visiting users (may be based on visitor's IP). Let's say I have 120 visitors to my site, I want to evenly distribute them among available four variants (30 visitors each). It doesn't have to be exact. We can also assume that there won't be any returning users. 
I'm using Ubuntu LAMP stack. Please help me with the PHP code.

Comment: You need to keep track of the visitors. So probably storing the IP in database would be a good choice. And make the assignment of webpage based on this list after querying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up a simple A/B testing with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210093/setting-up-a-simple-a-b-testing-with-php)